# dynamically show n hide table rows using jquery :gt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to use jQuery's `:gt()` in an inclusive way. I am trying to show/hide table rows dynamically.

```
$('#' + tbodyId + ' > tr:gt(' + newRowStart + '):lt(' + rowsToShow + ')').show();
```

If i try to show the first 5 rows say, `newRowStart = 0` and `rowsToShow = 5`. This will not show the first row. Setting it to -1 doesn't work either. It would be very helpful if there was an inclusive method like `:gt()`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: maybe $('#' + tbodyId + ' > td').filter(':gt(variable)').filter(':lt(variable)').show(); works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use slice():

```
$('#'+tbodyId)
  .find('tr')
  .slice( newRowStart, newRowStart + rowsToShow ) // inclusive of starting point
  .show();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just use [`.slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('#' + tbodyId + ' > tr').slice(newRowStart, newRowStart + rowsToShow).show();
// or if rowsToShow is an index actually:
$('#' + tbodyId + ' > tr').slice(newRowStart, rowsToShow).show();
```

It's also a bit easier to read.

> It would be very helpful if there was an inclusive method like `:gt()`

Not that I know of. If you want to include all elements from a given index on, you either have to use `:gt(index-1)` or omit `:gt` completely if the index is 0.